# JSon authentication for geni.com

Tags: json, authentication, ios, ios4

I wanted to create a app using some functions of GENI.com. But, I can't find how I can authenticate the user. I don't find it a good solution to let the user first login at geni.com in order for me to be able to use the API functions.

I thought of using the function "immediate_family" in a iOS device.

Anyone who has any experience with this?

API documentation: http://wiki.geni.com/index.php/Api

Best regards,
Paul Peelen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can authenticate HTTP digest authentication or OAuth.
You can register your OAuth application [here](http://www.geni.com/client_applications)

Answer (score 1):

You can now get all you need here :

http://dev.geni.com